# Angular 2 executing method after http.get from another component has finished

Tags: angular

I have a service called `JwtService`. This service has a method to get the user data. I call this method in my component:

```
this.JwtService.getUserData();
```

Now, whenever I click a button in my component - I call this method.
After this method is called, I call another local method:

```
this.updateMoves();
```

which works on the data in the `JwtService` service.

The problem is that `this.JwtService.getUserData();` is not finished executing and update the new data, and `this.updateMoves();` executed on the old data.

**Unwanted solution:** Moving the `updateMoves()` method to the service and call it after the response is received can make it work, but since this method belong to specific one component, I don't wanna do that.

**Unwanted solution 2:** new service variable `IS_LOADED` and check in my component if it has finished loading. It causes some problems in my app.

Any other solution that might work to run `updateMoves()` after service data has received?

My getUserData() method:

```
getUserData()
    {
        this.good = false;
    if (this.getToken()) {
    this.http.get('user/info?token='+this.getToken())
      .map((res:Response) => res.json())
      .subscribe(
        data => {
            this.userData = data.user;
            this.LOADED = true; 
        },
        err => { this.checkToken(err); }
      );
    }
}
```

Comment: you should add code of your Component class and decorator to the post, hard top guess what's happening there

Comment: You could return an Observable from your `getUserData()` method, so you can execute everything else after it succeeded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `getUserData` method returns an observable, you could subscribe on it and execute the second method in the associated callback:

```
this.JwtService.getUserData().subscribe(() => {
  this.updateMoves();
});
```

**Edit**

You could use the `do` and `catch` operators:

```
getUserData() {
  this.good = false;
  if (this.getToken()) {
    return this.http.get('user/info?token='+this.getToken())
      .map((res:Response) => res.json())
      .do(
        data => {
          this.userData = data.user;
          this.LOADED = true; 
      })
      .catch(
        err => { this.checkToken(err); }
    );
  } else {
    return Observable.throw('Not good');
  }
}
```

Comment: I have variable named `userData` equals to the response object which is used all across my application, if changing the method to return an observable will not allow me to update the `userData` variable and force me to fetch it again for each component, it seem like a bad idea. Please have a look at my current `getuserdata` method

Comment: Thanks for sharing your method. You could leverage the `do` and `catch` operator instead. I udpated my answer...

Comment: Awesome thank you! Just for making sure, if I want to run `getUserData() `without executing any code when it's done, I should just leave the brackets {} empty or there is any cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: You're welcome! Yes exactly, an empty function is fine. But you need to subscribe otherwise your request won't be execute...

Comment: Hey @Thierry Templier, I just tried to compile my app today and i get the following error: `error TS2345: Argument of type '(err: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<any>) => Observable<{}>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Observable<{}>'.` in this line: `err => { this.checkToken(err); }`. why?

Comment: You could tr y to return null at the end of this callback.